# platform specific styles do not inherit from component style

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have trouble with the styles when platform specific CSS files come into play.

See the files below:

items.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ns-items',
  moduleId: module.id,
  template: `
      <Label [nsRouterLink]="['/item', item.id]" [text]="item.name"
             class="list-group-item"></Label>
  `,

  styleUrls: ['./items.component.css' ]
})
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {
  items: Item[];

  constructor(private itemService: ItemService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.items = this.itemService.getItems();
  }
}
```

items.component.css:

```
Label {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

items.component.ios.css:

```
Label {
    background-color: red;
}
```

items.component.android.css is empty.

On iOS, it behaves as expected, the `Label`s background color is red.
On Android, the `Label`s background color has not changes at all. The behaviour I expect is that it inherits the styles from `items.component.css`, so the `Label`s background color should be blue, which it isn't.

I tried to add `@import items.component.css` in the `items.component.android.css` but then I get a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error because I'm declaring the CSS already in the component.

What is the correct way to have the component-global CSS and then the platform specific ones which inherit from the component-global one? Or am I doing something plain wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What is component-global supposed to mean? With ViewEncapsulation.Emulated (default setting) and .Native (browsers native way to do the same as emulated, but only few browsers have implemented it; no not use at all!) the styles from your component apply only to the component.

Well, unless you use the `:host ::ng-deep` selectors in your css, in which case they are also applied to underlying child-components. But that is not recommended because this feature will be deprecated in Chrome some day, so instead you should use @Input() to pass styles/configs to underlying components if you really need to.

If you want global styles you can either declare them in a global assets-folder and include it in the angular-cli.json as assets.

Or you can set ViewEncapsulation.None for one specific component whose styles will leak into the rest of the app. I do not recommend this approach as it is confusing where the applied global styles are coming from, even if you do that in a core-component responsible for theming. Google's Angular-Material library doesn't use ViewEncapsulation.None either.

TLDR: use only angular-cli.json to embed global css-files.